# To build an a web application which access a database, do you use Kendo UI or Telerik?

Tags: asp.net

To build an a web application which access a database, do you use Kendo UI or Telerik? What are the difference between these two?

Does Telerik or KendoUI have auto code generation to generate form for basic things such as login and etc.

Can it auto generate WCF from from the Database?

Comment: Have you [thoroughly searched for an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/search) before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps _you_ get a more specific and relevant answer!  See also [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and [What makes a good question?](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Answer (score 0):

You do know that Kendo UI is a product of Telerik, right?  Your question is akin to asking "I am installing an operating system on my PC, should I use Windows 8 or Microsoft?".  I would suggest doing some more research and then asking a more specific question, the Telerik website is a great place to start:

[Telerik website](http://www.telerik.com/)